# Is There Any Way To Get The Preview Results From API Request Like in the Inspect Section From Browser

Tags: javascript, php

I try to Call a PHP function with Javascript, i saw someone here given an example how to do it with API FETCH and It Worked but My Javascript Return My HTML file too. Look at The Pic:

[image: Return the Data but with the HTML File as Well]

so When i try to Return a JSON it will get an ERROR : unexpexted token....is not a valid JSON.

but when i saw the preview section it return the data only :

[image: Data Only on Preview]

the Code You Saw in the Response Section is exactly my HTML file that requesting the Data. and This is the PHP code thats been Requested

```
<?php
require_once('../index.php');
require_once(app_path('Config/Constants.php'));

if(isset($_GET['request'])){
    if(isset($_GET['params'])){
        $params = $_GET['params'];
    }else{
        $params = 'no_params=true';
    }

    function getIt($request,$params){
        $url = HST.$request.'api_key='.AKY.$params;
        $ch = curl_init();
        $options = [
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0
        ];
        curl_setopt_array($ch,$options);
        $results = curl_exec($ch);
        // pretending return the results
        echo "This Is The Result, BRO!";
        curl_close($ch);

    }

    getIt($request,$params);
}else{
    echo "Request Invalid Or Does Not Exist";
}
```

the weird thing is, when i try to do it with AJAX it worked it does not return the HTML file. but the case here is i have to do it with Pure Javascript, Logic Exercise my teacher said. here is the JS Code :

```
function getIt($url){
    $response = fetch($url).then(res => res.json());
    return $response;
}

results = getIt('php/fknit.php?request=/trending/all/day');
results.then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
})
```

im pretty sure the problem is in My JS. Is There Anyway just to get the Preview or is There a way to do it rightly, because im sure my method is the worst out there.

Comment: `"This Is The Result, BRO!"` is not JSON

Comment: i know, it just pretending i return a json

Comment: the error is that <DOCTYPE> so even when i return a JSON its still an error

Comment: yeah, you probably need to fix PHP to send JSON

Comment: Dude, its that html file that make the error. "even when i return a JSON its still an error" bcz it return the HTML as well

Comment: `that html file` ... no, it's PHP that sends the result, not HTML ... dude

Comment: i know its the PHP who send the result i mean its the HTML code that make the Error. look at Response section. why is there even a HTML code in the result

Comment: i fetch a PHP file, but why my js return its HTML code. thats the question

Comment: your server could be sending the wrong thing - what server are you running?

Comment: nvm i think i found the problem. its laravel who added that HTML. its request the View Twice, that's what makes there's an HTML code on the response.

Comment: When you send JSON you also need to send the `header('Content-Type: application/json'); echo json_encode(['message' => 'Hi, Bro']);` else the browser assume it is HTML.